# Baire 1 functions are closed under uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, definition, uniform-convergence, baire-category

May I know what does it mean by "*functions are closed*" under uniform convergence?

Also, how do I then prove that Baire-1 functions are closed under uniform convergence using the epsilon-delta definition of Baire-1 functions?

Comment: You need some more context. From what space to what space are you thinking of? Do you mean that the collection of functions is closed or that the each function is closed?

Comment: I am looking at the paper "On Some Properties of Baire-1 Functions". It states in the introduction that the proof for the class of Baire-1 functions is closed under uniform convergence using the epsilon-delta characterisation is short and easy. I was wondering how to prove it. I think we are only looking at the real line.

Comment: Are you working with the definition given in the article or the following definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function ?

Comment: I am working with the definition of "f: R->R" is baire 1 for every epsilon>0, there is a positive real valued function d on R such that for any x,y on R, | x - y | < min{ d(x), d(y)} implies | f(x) - f(y) | < epsilon . "

Comment: Assume you have a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of Baire class $1$ function, uniformly converging to $f$. Each $f_n$ is the point wise limit of $(f_{n,m})_m$, where each $f_{n,m}$ is continuous. Can you find a sequence $(g_n)_n$ of continuous functions converging point wise to $f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So uniform convergence, $f_n \twoheadrightarrow f$ ,  means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$, such that if $n>N_\epsilon$, then $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert <\epsilon$.

What you want to show is that $f$ is Baire-1. So you need to find a function $\delta'_\epsilon:\mathbb{R}\to (0,\infty)$ such that if $\vert x-y \vert< \min\{ \delta'_\epsilon(x),\delta'_\epsilon(y) \}$, then $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert<\epsilon$.

Every $f_n$ is Baire-$1$, so has such a $\delta^{(n)}_{ \frac{ \epsilon}{3} }$ function.
By the triangle inequality, you obtain

$$ \vert f(x)-f(y) \vert\leq \vert f(x)-f_n(x) \vert+ \vert f_n(x)-f_n(y) \vert +\vert f_n(y) -f(y) \vert   $$

for all $n$. The two outer most terms on the RHS are both smaller than $\frac{\epsilon} {3}$ when $n>N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$ by uniform convergence. The middle term of the RHS, when $n=N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}+1$, is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ when $\vert x-y\vert<\min\Big\{ \delta^{(N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}+1)}_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}(x),\delta^{(N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}+1)}_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}(y) \Big\}$, since $f_{N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}+1}$ is a Baire-$1$ function.

So using the function $\delta'_\epsilon=\delta^{(N_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}+1)}_{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$, you get that $f$ is a Baire-$1$ function.

This is considered easy since bounding the difference from above by $k$ terms, and then bounding each of the $k$-terms by $\frac{\epsilon}{k}$ is used alot when showing uniform convergence preserve certain properties.

Edit: I just looked up the paper, and saw that this is literally Theorem 4 in it.

Comment: May I know why every fn is Baire-1? Is it because of the theorem that says if {fn} is a sequence of Baire 1 functions that converges uniformly to f, then f is Baire-1? I get an idea of how you are proving that f is Baire-1, but may I know how does it show that the baire 1 function is closed? Thank you.

Comment: What would you refer to as uniform convergence then? Saying a set $E$ is closed in a metric space $X$, is equivalent to saying that if $e_n\to e$ where $e_n\in E$ then $e\in E$. You are saying that the collection of Baire-$1$ functions is closed.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I understand what you are saying now.